# warning: unable to unlink | error: unable to write symref for HEAD: operation not permitted

Tags: github, terminal, git-clone

I am working on a project that has a private repo in Github. I've made several attempts to clone project.

```
warning; unable to unlink ‘Users/Jett/Desktop/this_awesome_file/.git/HEAD.lock’ 

error: unable to write symref for HEAD: Operation not permitted
```

I am working in Bash.

I've tried `git clone https_url_project` then get the warning and error message.

I’ve tried $ `brew update`, `brew upgrade` to fix issue.

I’ve tried updating to newest version of git.

I’ve tried `git reset —-hard`

I've also researched this issue online and found that I should delete .gitconfig.lock file and .gitconfig file and still nothing works.

Still gives me the same message. I’m operating on macOS Ventura

Comment: Do you have any other process using that Git repo? Like an editor that has a Git plugin?

Comment: @ZacAnger I recently removed Git from Visual Studio Code because its just too confusing starting out learning github and git in general. So i only work through terminal. I've recently had access to the private repo and never got the chance to clone it and work through it due to this issue.

Comment: If it's currently open, try closing VSCode completely. That file gets locked when some process is doing _something_ Git-related in the repo.

Comment: I've closed VSC completely and disabled git from source control as well. Seem like I've tried everything. Never had this issue before never had issues push/commit changes to repos etc...I am working on a project that is due on the 7th. So it is a bit overwhelming @ZacAnger

Comment: In that case, as long as there's nothing else wrong with your repo, you can `rm .git/HEAD.lock`. The lockfile exists to make sure multiple processes aren't making changes at the same time, but this sounds like it failed to get cleaned up when some process was finished what it was doing.

Comment: I've tried deleting .git/HEAD.lock too and still receive the same message when attempting to clone project. Not sure what else I could try at this point. @ZacAnger

Comment: Are you running `git clone` when you already have the repo on disk, from the same directory or its parent directory?

Comment: Step 1: I open terminal and locate the directory on which I choose to clone repo. Step 2: I copy/paste the url from the private repo into terminal for instance: "git clone Url_exmaple_proj" then the message in terminal states: Cloning into  'this_awesome_file'... warning: unable to unlink .... operation not permitted error: unable to write symref for HEAD: operation not permitted @ZacAnger